# Menu Button in Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying do a button in a responsive layout. It needs to be hidden sometimes and show itself when the screen is small, I see a code that do it with vanilla js. But i'm using typescript, the problem it is in the  typing typescript. Can someone help me with that?

The code:

```js
function Menu(e){
    let list = document.querySelector('ul');
    e.name === 'menu' ? (e.name = "close",list.classList.add('top-[80px]') , list.classList.add('opacity-100')) :( e.name = "menu" ,list.classList.remove('top-[80px]'),list.classList.remove('opacity-100'))
}
```

The button:

```html
<button className={styles.burgerButton} onClick={}></button>
```

I need the button call the function rightly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged for react.js please see the below code, not created by me.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [showBlueBox, setShowBlueBox] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        <strong>
          <i>
            Task: Convert the two buttons into single button , so that clicking
            on the button toggles the visibility of the blue box
          </i>
        </strong>
      </p>
      <button disabled={!showBlueBox} onClick={() => setShowBlueBox(false)}>
        Hide blue box
      </button>
      <button disabled={showBlueBox} onClick={() => setShowBlueBox(true)}>
        show blue box
      </button>
      {showBlueBox ? <div className="box">Blue Box</div> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d2zquo?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: It's close. But I not using two buttons. The idea of to use ```use state``` was greatting. I'll use that to solve my problem. Thanks!